# Why is this while loop running endlessly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

```py
def get_password():
    password = passwd() #returns None when no input is given else return password
    if password is not None:
        if len(password)<7:
            print("Minimum length of password is 6. Please try again.")
            password = None
        elif len(password)>16:
            print("Maximum length of password is 16. Please try again.")
            password = None
        while password is None:
            get_password()
    return password
```

I want to run this function again and again until users inputs a valid password. If user gives a valid password then while loop should not be entered but even then the loop is getting executed endlessly.

Comment: Don't run a method recursivly (call it inside itself) to have a logic a "do it again"

Comment: `self.get_password()` can't work at all, please share a working, reproducible example

Comment: @azro it was a class method. Forgot to remove self. :)

Comment: You don't do anything with the return value of the recursive call, thus `password` never changes and the loop never ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use recursivity to have a logic of "do that again", because when you need to stop it, recursivity is for specific problems

Use a main loop based on `password is None`, then call `passwd` and apply your rules

```py
def get_password():
    password = None
    while password is None:
        password = passwd()  # returns None when no input is given else return password
        if password is not None:
            if len(password) < 7:
                print("Minimum length of password is 6. Please try again.")
                password = None
            elif len(password) > 16:
                print("Too Long", "Maximum length of password is 16. Please try again.")
                password = None
    return password
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_password():
passwd = False
while passwd == False:
    password = input("Type your password")
    if len(password) == 0:
        passwd = False
    elif len(password)<7:
        print("Minimum length of password is 6. Please try again.")
        passwd = False
    elif len(password)>16:
        print("Too Long", "Maximum length of password is 16. Please try again.")
        passwd = False
    else:
        passwd = True
        return password
        print(password)
```